# How to select employee full name, from three different tables

Tags: mysql

I have three table `person_firstname`,`person_middlename`,`person_lastname`. All tables have common field `entity_id`. I have to select employee full name in single record . It is not sure person have only first name, all name or only last name.  I tried union it returns three row.

Also need record of specific employee that is by entity_id. SO need to match record like entity_id=123. All names of employee whose entity_id is 123.

Comment: Is every employee guaranteed to have a last name?

Comment: No employee could have first,last,middle, all or none name . Every thing is optional.

Comment: You are going to need a really ugly set of simulated outer joins.

Comment: I have to do anyway . Will try to optimize as much possible.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p1.first_name person_firstname,p2.middle_name person_middlename,p3.last_name person_lastname
FROM person_firstname p1 JOIN person_middlename p2 ON p1.entity_id=p2.entity_id
JOIN person_lastname p3 ON p3.entity_id=p2.entity_id;

Comment: thanks for response but it is not sure which table contains record one,two or all . So i think on will not work and need to get specific record .  Like were entity_id=123. Entity_id represents employee id.

Comment: you can use USING clause with entity_id but i m nt sure it will work

Comment: for 2tables it will be-

Comment: SELECT p1.first_name First_Name,p2.last_name Last_Name FROM First_Name p1 JOIN Last_Name p2 USING (entity_id);

Comment: It's working for two tables tried but i need to run on three tables.Also i can't use where entity_id=123 condition.

Comment: @Moreshwar, please provide explation for your answer. This will help other users.

Comment: instead of where clause you can use USING clause along with JOIN for maintening relation between two tables.....bt i dont know it will work for three tables or not

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
DROP TABLE PERSON_FIRSTNAME;
DROP TABLE PERSON_SECONDNAME;
DROP TABLE PERSON_LASTNAME;

CREATE TABLE PERSON_FIRSTNAME (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE PERSON_SECONDNAME (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE PERSON_LASTNAME (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));
TRUNCATE TABLE PERSON_FIRSTNAME;
INSERT INTO PERSON_FIRSTNAME VALUES(1,'af'),(2,'bf') ; 
TRUNCATE TABLE PERSON_SECONDNAME;
INSERT INTO PERSON_SECONDNAME VALUES(1,'as') ,(3,'cs') ; 
TRUNCATE TABLE PERSON_LASTNAME;
INSERT INTO PERSON_LASTNAME VALUES(1,'al'),(2,'bl') ; 
*/

SELECT  S.*, 
        PF.NAME,
        PS.NAME,
        PL.NAME,
        concat(IFnull(PF.NAME,''),IFnull(PS.NAME,''),IFNULL(PL.NAME,''))
FROM
(
SELECT  ID FROM PERSON_FIRSTNAME
UNION   
SELECT  ID FROM PERSON_SECONDNAME
UNION   
SELECT  ID FROM PERSON_LASTNAME
) S
left outer JOIN PERSON_FIRSTNAME    PF ON PF.ID = S.ID
left outer JOIN PERSON_SECONDNAME   PS ON PS.ID = S.ID
left outer JOIN PERSON_LASTNAME     PL ON PL.ID = S.ID
```

Comment: DB is part of already running application. I am adding feature . So to add feature i cant not modify the structure of db. I think as i described there is no certainty  that for a record data will be available in all table. If not then join will fail to fetch data as per my understanding.

Comment: You are developing on production? Oh dear...The tables in my solution are there to prove the solution works and they are commented out. If you have a development environment you should create the tables and run the select to help you understand what the solution is doing, in brief the sub-query (the bit with the unions in it) looks at all the tables and creates a temporary table with DISTINCT IDs across all the tables. The outer query then left outer joins all the tables to the sub-query. And no the left outer join does not fail - a left join (which is not the same) would.